# Gulp tool to change pathing in index html dynamically without concat

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, gulp-inject

So I have all working the way I want except mainly that once I run 'gulp copy', my index.html paths stay what they were. However, when running gulp copy, it runs several tasks and the spits the dest to '/dist/....'. This is a problem as my dev environment is different. Have been searching and searching and thought how I could implement something like gulp-inject, but not sure exactly the best way to do considering my file structures as shown below. Below I am including my gulp.js and my index.html. Hoping someone can help resolve this.

gulp.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');  
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var open = require('gulp-open');
// var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
// var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

var bases = {
    app: 'app/',
    dist: 'dist/',
};
var paths = {
    scripts: ['ppt/scripts/**/*.js'],
    styles: ['ppt/styles/**/*.css'],
    html: ['ppt/views/**/*.html'],
    assets: ['ppt/assets/**/*.png', 'ppt/assets/**/*.svg'],
    extras: ['index.html', '404.html', 'robots.txt', 'favicon.ico'],
};

gulp.task('connect', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: '.',
        port: 9000,
        // livereload: true,
        open: {
            browser: 'chrome'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('open', function(){
  gulp.src('./index.html')
  .pipe(open());
});

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    // mainBowerFiles is used as a src for the task,
    // usually you pipe stuff through a task
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        // Then pipe it to wanted directory, I use
        // dist/lib but it could be anything really
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib'))
});

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src(bases.dist).pipe(clean());
});
// Process scripts and concatenate them into one output file
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.src(paths.scripts, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(uglify()).pipe(concat('app.min.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'scripts/'));
});
// Imagemin images and ouput them in dist
// gulp.task('imagemin', ['clean'], function() {
//     gulp.src(paths.images, {
//         cwd: bases.app
//     }).pipe(imagemin()).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'assets/'));
// });
// Copy all other files to dist directly
gulp.task('copy', ['clean', 'scripts', 'bower'], function() {
    // Copy html
    gulp.src(paths.html, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'views'));
    // Copy styles
    gulp.src(paths.styles, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'styles'));
    //Copy assets
    gulp.src(paths.assets, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'assets'));
    // Copy app scripts
    // gulp.src(paths.scripts, {
    //     cwd: bases.app
    // }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'scripts'));
    // Copy extra html5bp files
    gulp.src(paths.extras, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});
// Process scripts and concatenate them into one output file
gulp.task('scriptstrip', function() {
 gulp.src(paths.scripts, {cwd: bases.app})
 // .pipe(jshint())
 // .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'scripts/'));
});
// A development task to run anytime a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*', ['scripts', 'copy']);
});
// Define the default task as a sequence of the above tasks
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'scripts', 'copy']);
```

And now, my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="fpsClientApp">
  <head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="flexible fsa hsa commuter health wellness medical dental benefits" />
    <meta name="description" content="Navia Benefit Solutions" />
    <meta content="IE=edge, chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <title>Navia Benefit Solutions</title>
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="ppt/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- fonts imported from Google fonts cdn    -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,400italic|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" ng-click="navbarExpanded = !navbarExpanded">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/pptHome"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!navbarExpanded">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ng-show="authentication.isAdmin"><a href="#/admin/ppt">admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/products-and-services/" target="_blank">products + services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/about/" target="_blank">about us</a></li>`
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/testimonials/" target="_blank">testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/careers/" target="_blank">careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/news/" target="_blank">news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/blog/" target="_blank">blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/contact/" target="_blank">contact us</a></li>
                    <li ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a id="signOut" href="" ng-click="logOut()">sign out <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbarSecondary navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController" ng-show="authentication.isAuth">
        <div class="container">
            <div  ng-include="'ppt/views/menu.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div ng-view="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController">
        <div class="container">
<!--             <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/pptHome"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia-icon.png" alt="Navia Logo"></a>
            </div> -->
            <div class="footerLinks">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                    <img style="height: 37px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;" src="ppt/assets/navia-icon.png" alt="Navia Logo">
                    <li class="copyNavia"><a href="#">Navia © copyright 2016</a></li>
                    <li class="socialLinks"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/FlexPlanServices" target="_blank"><img src="ppt/assets/Facebook.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="socialLinks"><a href="https://twitter.com/FlexPlanService" target="_blank"><img src="ppt/assets/Twitter.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="socialLinks"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/FlexPlanServices" target="_blank"><img src="ppt/assets/YouTube.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="socialLinks"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/102136?trk=tyah&trkInfo=clickedVertical%3Acompany%2Cidx%3A1-1-1%2CtarId%3A1437085282797%2Ctas%3Aflex%20plan%20services" target="_blank"><img src="ppt/assets/LinkedIn.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="naviaLinks"><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/about/" target="_blank">Feedback</a></li>
                    <li id="naviaSeperator" class="naviaLinks"><a href="">|</a></li>
                    <li class="naviaLinks"><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/testimonials/" target="_blank">Help</a></li>
                    <li id="naviaSeperator" class="naviaLinks"><a href="">|</a></li>
                    <li class="naviaLinks"><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/careers/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li id="naviaSeperator" class="naviaLinks"><a href="">|</a></li>
                    <li class="naviaLinks"><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/news/" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd party libraries managed by Bower -->

    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/kendo-ui/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-validation-match/dist/angular-validation-match.js"></script>


    <!--     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Load app main script -->
    <script src="ppt/scripts/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Load services -->
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/authService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/pptService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/claimsService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/swipesService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/recurService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/tokensManagerService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/docsService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/ordersService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/errorService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/utilsService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/cardsService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/mobileAppService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/oeService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/statementService.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/services/employeeService.js"></script>

    <!-- Load controllers -->
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/infoController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/pptController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/pptProfileController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/signupController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/forgotController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/pptERSuccessController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/swipeController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/claimsController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/claimReceiptController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/recurController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/docs/docsController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/orders/ordersController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/orders/orderController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/oe/onlineEnrollmentController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/refreshController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/tokensManagerController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/associateController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/cards/cardsController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/mobileapp/mobileAppController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/statementController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/employee/employeeController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/admin/adminController.js"></script>
    <script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/ssoController.js"></script>


    <!-- Load custom filters -->
    <!-- Load custom directives -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Really appreciate the help as I have been racking my brain most of the night on this.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep). It automatically handles all of your bower dependencies for you, as well as the order of the dependencies. Here is sample wiredep task:

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

gulp.task('wiredep',  function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// Wires bower dependencies by inserting the css and js files used by the app.
    /// The <!--bower:css--> and <!--bower:js--> tags followed by <!--endbower -->
    /// indicating the insertion points.
    /// </summary>

    return gulp
        .src("** Your index.html file path ***")
        .pipe(wiredep("** Your bower folder path **"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("** Where you want your new index.html ***")); // it could be the same path
});
```

Notice that there is no concatenation.

Also, I recommend using [gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins). It will make your life sooo... much easier.